# is there a way to convert from xml to json?

Tags: c#, xml, json, google-reader

I'm writing an api for google reader where I'm currently trying to get items belonging to a specific inputted feed. In order to get the information i am using the following code:

```
String url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/{0}?n=5000", inputtedURL);
```

The information returned is in XML format. Is there a way where I can specify the output to be in JSON format in the url itself? Or else, is there an assembly reference (library) in C# which can perform this conversion please?

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a feed as JSON from the Google Reader API by using `http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/<feed_url>`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: [Help link for XML/JSON conversion](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/ConvertingJSONandXML.html)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an native c# library that can do it but here is a couple of methods to do it for you.

[XML to JSON](http://www.phdcc.com/xml2json.htm)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just parse your XML and serialize into a json file?

Answer (score 0):

see:
http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html
http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending "&output=json" to the querystring? [The tutorial for the API](http://blog.martindoms.com/2009/10/16/using-the-google-reader-api-part-2/) has an example.